# Limit amount of stored rows on a Cloud Spanner table

Tags: sql, transactions, google-cloud-spanner

I need to limit the number of rows stored per user on a Cloud Spanner table. In other RDBMS I'd probably have implemented this using a trigger but that's not an option in Spanner. This is a simplified table structure:

```sql
CREATE TABLE user_searches (
    search_id STRING(MAX) NOT NULL,
    user_id STRING(MAX) NOT NULL,
    search_text STRING(MAX) NOT NULL,
    occurred_on TIMESTAMP NOT NULL
) PRIMARY KEY (search_id);
```

In my use case, I want to make sure each user has only the most recent 20 searches.

Right now, this is what I'm doing (at the application code):

1. When a new search occurs, trigger a read-write transaction that:
   a) Writes the search
   b) Returns the count of stored searches per user
2. Then if count + 1 > 20, I trigger a new transaction that deletes all oldest searches for a user, that aren't within "the 20 limit".

Searches are constantly happening (~1M searches a day) so this table will be constantly written/read and I want to avoid locking as possible.

Should I be doing this on a single transaction? Or should I be making them on different transactions? Is there a better approach?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Cloud Spanner has Time to live (TTL) feature that helps you automatically delete rows periodically. You can use the TTL feature to keep expiring the searches if you have a pattern of the number of searches per timestamp. Please find more details here - https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/ttl.

Alternatively, you can write a separate query that scans user_searches table and periodically deletes the oldest rows and keeping the count to 20. Currently, there is no trigger function available.